# Java Thread lags/long sleeps on Ubuntu/Jetty

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jetty, dwr

I am running Java web server on  Jetty 6 on Ubunu,for reverse-ajax based web. And I have serious problems with lagging threads which resend data to browsers. Very often some thread just start to sleep for long time. Like 1 sec and more, sometimes even hours.  I thought first that it is bug of ajax library (DWR), than that it is Jetty problem, than that it is Java bug, but all suspicions are probably wrong. I lost weeks trying to solve this issue. I am completly lost.  The only think I didn't try is to run it on another OS, like windows. Here is the stacktrace of the thread which usually lags:

```
Cancelled at this stacktrace:   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.blockWritable(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:279)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.blockForOutput(AbstractGenerator.java:544)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.flush(AbstractGenerator.java:571)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$Output.flush(HttpConnection.java:997)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGenerator.java:648)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGenerator.java:579)
  at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:109)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$OutputWriter.write(AbstractGenerator.java:903)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$OutputWriter.write(AbstractGenerator.java:752)
  at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$OutputWriter.write(AbstractGenerator.java:741)
  at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:412)
  at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:429)
  at java.io.PrintWriter.print(PrintWriter.java:559)
  at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:695)
  at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.PlainScriptConduit.addScript(PlainScriptConduit.java:93)
  at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultScriptSession.addScript(DefaultScriptSession.java:239)
  at server.comunication.dwr.OneReverseDWRServer.sendLocalBuffer(OneReverseDWRServer.java:385)
  at server.comunication.dwr.OneReverseDWRServer.sendMessageLocal(OneReverseDWRServer.java:363)
  at server.comunication.dwr.OneReverseDWRServer.sendMessage(OneReverseDWRServer.java:412)
  at server.comunication.messaging.SendTask.call(SendTask.java:53)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

When I tried different jetty connection Selector, stack trace was different but it was waiting on some similar place. I tried many versions of combinations of Jetty and Java. I thought it might be NIO bug, but when I changed selector to non-nio, it was stacked on other place.

Can be problem on Linux? I am running it as root. Are there some setting in ubuntu which I can change to force waiting threads to weak up as they should?  Pls. help, I am completely lost here.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I know what reverse AJAX is, but I assume it is where the server is sending requests to the user's browser by the browser (in effect) sending periodic requests to ask for requests.

I imagine that what is happening is that the browser is occasionally not requesting requests, and this is causing server-side threads to get stuck occasionally.

This unlikely to be a bug in nio versus non-nio, in the version of Java you are using, in the version of Jetty, or in Linux.

It might be a bug in the DWR library you are using, but it also might just be inherent in what you are doing.  For instance, if the user closes the browser window or pane that is running the client-side ... or if there is a network disruption ... then the browser may simply fail to make the request for a request.  The server thread is then potentially stuck waiting for a client that never comes back.  If this is what is going on, then there needs to be something to unblock the server-side threads.  (I'd have thought that was DWR's responsibility, but I'm not an expert ...).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but it obviously is not a bug of DWR. I wrote with 2 main developers of DWR and both said me, that it is not bug of DWR, but probably Jetty.But I tried all versiond of Jetty, and bug is same in all of them, and I got no answer from Jetty forum. Problem is, that Jetty is best solutions thanks to its Continuation machanism, which can handle thousands of connections just in some constant number of threads.Other web containers use thread per connection model.I searched that bug and there is hudge number of people who has problem with NIO and JAVA 6 on Linux. But no solution.